# При запросе к файлу на сервере ответ один и тот же WinApi

Tags: winapi, сеть

В общем, проблема такова: я пытаюсь получить данные из текстового файла на сервере(~10 байт) с помощью WinInet таким образом, что:

- Есть функция, которая возвращает содержимое файла
- Создается новый поток с этой функцией в зацикленном виде, с перерывом в 10 секунд

Запрос отправляется, ответ приходит, но если содержимое файла изменилось - ответ почему-то не меняется.

Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <thread>
#pragma comment(lib,"wininet")
using namespace std;
string flag;
    string getresponse(){ //сама функция получения ответа
    string ret;
      bool ok = false;
    HINTERNET hInternet =
        ::InternetOpen(
            TEXT("WinInet Test"),
            INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,
            NULL,NULL,
            0);

    if (hInternet != NULL) {
        HINTERNET hConnect = 
            ::InternetConnect(
                hInternet,
                TEXT("www.applang.tk"),
                INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,
                NULL,NULL,
                INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,
                0,
                1u);

        if (hConnect != NULL) {
            HINTERNET hRequest = 
                ::HttpOpenRequest(
                    hConnect,
                    TEXT("GET"),
                    TEXT("baget/com"),
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    0,
                    INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION,
                    1);

            if (hRequest != NULL) {
                BOOL bSend = ::HttpSendRequest(hRequest, NULL,0, NULL,0);
                if (bSend) {
                    for (;;) {
                        char  szData[1024];
                        DWORD dwBytesRead;
                        BOOL bRead = 
                            ::InternetReadFile(
                                hRequest,
                                szData,sizeof(szData)-1,
                                &dwBytesRead);
                        if (bRead == FALSE  ||  dwBytesRead == 0)
                            break;
                        szData[dwBytesRead] = 0;
                        ret = string(szData,strlen(szData));

                        ok = true;
                    }
                }
                ::InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
            }
            ::InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
            }
            ::InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
        }
        return ret;
    }



    void syncserv(string arg){ //вспомогательная функция
    while(true){
    cout<<"SENT REQUEST"<<endl;
    flag = getresponse();
        cout <<"GOT RESPONSE: "<<flag<<endl;
        Sleep(10000);
    }
    }


    main(){
    thread t1(syncserv, "something"); //создаем поток
    getch();
    }
```

Comment: Код скопировали и даже не почитали про используемые в нем WinApi функции? Рекомендую почитать, поможет. Особенно поинтересуйтесь разными флагами, используемыми в функциях. Также погуглите такое понятие как CACHE. И еще... Данный вопрос ну абсолютно никакого отношения к С++ не имеет. Измените тэг с С++ на Winapi.

Comment: Да насчет кэширования я думал, посмотрю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю, как Вы искали информацию про кэш, но для каждой из данных функций в MSDN есть информация о кэшировании.

Для [HttpSendRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) есть флаги INTERNET_FLAG_FROM_CACHE и INTERNET_FLAG_OFFLINE.

Для [InternetConnect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) кэширование упоминается в примечании.

Для функции [HttpOpenRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) есть INTERNET_FLAG_CACHE_IF_NET_FAIL, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD.

И для функций [HttpSendRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , [InternetReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) кэш упоминается в примечаниях.

Не надо упоминать о том, что там якобы написано, когда невозможно подключиться к сети. Да, в некоторых случаях описано поведение и в автономном/оффлайн режиме и в случае ошибки и недоступности сети. Тогда тоже данные берутся из кэша. Но нам же неизвестны все условия Вашего тестирования.

А самое интересное - это если почитать примечания ***HttpOpenRequest*** и ***InternetReadFile***.

```
Note that caching happens automatically unless the original request to open the data stream set the INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE flag.

If a verb other than "GET" or "POST" is specified, HttpOpenRequest automatically sets INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE and INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD for the request.
```

Можно было бы все это написать в комментариях, но, к сожалению, они не вмещают столько текста.